# Как заменить точки в строке на скобки?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

Есть строка:

```
$.DETAILS.1.PKG.1.USER_PARAMS.4.NAME
```

Нужно привести её к виду:

```
$.DETAILS(1).PKG(1).USER_PARAMS(4).NAME
```

Пытаюсь прикрутить `regexp_replace`, но что-то с шаблоном не выходит.

Использовать нужно в SQL:

```
select ??? from (
  select '$.DETAILS.1.PKG.1.USER_PARAMS.4.NAME' a from dual) t
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так на скорую руку:

```
select regexp_replace (a, '\.(\d+)\.', '(\1).') result from (
    select '$.DETAILS.1.PKG.1.USER_PARAMS.4.NAME' a from dual) t
/

RESULT
---------------------------------------
$.DETAILS(1).PKG(1).USER_PARAMS(4).NAME
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только все-таки убрал одну точку из шаблона чтобы корректно обработался случай, когде строка заканчивается на число:

`select regexp_replace (a, '\.(\d+)\.', '(\1).') result,
       regexp_replace (a, '\.(\d+)', '(\1)') new_result from (
    select '$.DETAILS.1.PKG.1.USER_PARAMS.24.NAME.4' a from dual) t`

Оказывается вот как обозначается найденный шаблон. `\1`

Comment: _вот как обозначается найденный шаблон \1_, да так, и учесть, что группы для логического "или", например `(a|b|c)`, тоже надо учитывать для подсчёта, что поставить в `\n`.